# Query to get single year records

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to pull records those have only have 2019 end, not 2020 records.

example in below table 5105474 ,5105475,5105476 having 2019 end date. I need to get only those rows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select id
from t
group by id
having year(max(enddate)) = 2019;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT id FROM t WHERE YEAR(ENDDATE) = 2019
EXCEPT 
SELECT id FROM t WHERE YEAR(ENDDATE) = 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck with the [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

`WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, EndDate, 2019) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the max of your end date to not match the 2020 date per each group id as below.

```
      select id
      from table
      group by id where 
          HAVING max(enddate) NOT LIKE 
          '%2020%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to skin the cat. `WHERE...NOT EXISTS` should work for you.

```
select 
  id
from table as t
where 
  not exists 
    (
      select 1 
      from table as t1 
      where 
        t1.id = t.id 
        and 
        YEAR(t1.ENDDATE) = 2020
    );
```